# How to drag one UIView on another UIView and swap those two views?

Tags: ios5, uiview

I added 4 views in a window and I'm able to move those views by using ***touchesMoved*** method. My question is if I drag view1 on view2, the positions of view1 and view2 will be swapped. Similarly if i drag view1 on view3 or view4 the positions of those two views have to be swapped.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad language !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Thanks for your interest !!!

I used if condition to check which view is moving and then again I checked the touch point overlaps the other view's center point. If it returns yes then I swapped the colours of both views.